# Hystrix Dashboard Home page loading jquery fail

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, hystrix

I have a simple Hystrix Dashboard application running on port 8081 built on Spring Boot application with @EnableHystrixDashboard annotation.

**When I load the page http://localhost:8081/hystrix, I see the home page but with error: GET http://localhost:9001/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js 404 (), with which I cannot see the monitor page.**

Do I miss any thing here?

**Another problem is, when I make a Hystrix application also a Hystrix Dashboard and go to http://localhost:8081/hystrix, it will open a download page. Instead I have to go http://localhost:8081/hystrix.stream I can read the text data.**

Why is it?

Comment: what dependencies do you have in your pom?. Put your pom details regarding hystrix

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran. Pom is all fine. It turned out that one of the jar file which contains jquery file was broken.

Answer (score 0):

There was a warning message:

```
[WARNING] error reading .../.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery-2.1.1.jar invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Go to the directory; 
Delete the whole repository folder or jquery folder; 
Update your project with Force Update of Snapshots/Releases; 
Do maven clean and install;
Done.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same problem a few days ago, finally I fixed it.
The reason why you found 404 of jquery.min.js and hystrix-logo.png is that WebAutoConfigure is not initialized. So the static resource path is not added to the classpath of Spring Boot. If you want initialize web auto config, you must not use JavaConfig which extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport and must not use annotation @EnableWebMvc. You can use JavaConfig implements WebMvcConfigure which will not prevent web auto config.
Just like below:

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Spring Security. Make sure that you give access permissions for the following paths: /actuator, /hystrix, /webjars, /proxy.stream